# How to port a Pawn interpreter on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, pawn

For Linux platform I did the following

```
git clone https://github.com/compuphase/pawn.git
cd pawn
mk dir build
cd build
cmake ../
make all -j4
```

At this point I see the files created

amxArgs.so, amxDGram.so, amxFile.so, amxFixed.so, amxFloat.so,
amxProcess.so, amxStrimg.so, amxTime.so.

In the project (Qt)

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/pawn/build 
INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/pawn/amx 
INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/pawn/linux
```

Now in

```
#include "amx.h"
#include "amx.h"
int Pawn_Setup(char *file_name) 
{
    AMX amx;
    size_t memsize;
    int err;
    cell ret = 0;
    
     //memsize = aux_ProgramSize(file_name);
     //err = aux_LoadProgram(&amx, argv[1], program);

    err = amx_Exec(&amx, &ret, AMX_EXEC_MAIN);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error - "undefined reference to amx_Exec"  (although it sees the header files and Goto reference jumps to amx_Exec function).
Now I go to the build folder and I see no amx.so and no amaux.so files. It's not included in the make file.

What do I miss?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I've managed to port it. This should be added to the project LIBS += -ldl

INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/pawn/amx
INCLUDEPATH += /home/pi/pawn/linux

SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/amx/amx.c
SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/amx/amxcore.c
SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/amx/amxcons.c
SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/amx/amxaux.c
SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/linux/getch.c
SOURCES += /home/pi/pawn/amx/amxexec_gcc.c